# Random time and date

Tags: java, datetime, duration, period, localdatetime

I want to get a date that generates the time from now to 2685 days back and a random time. The format I accept must be "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH: mm: ssZ". Currently my program is generating a random date but I am not able to create a random time because Duration conflicts with Period

```
public static String generateRandomDateAndTimeInString() {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now()
            .minus(Period.ofDays((new Random().nextInt(2685))));
    return formatDate(date);
}

public static String formatDate(LocalDate date) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    return date.atStartOfDay().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(dtf);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Duration conflicts with Period"? I don't see `Duration` in your code (only `Period`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may be?

```
public static String generateRandomDateAndTimeInString() {
    ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now()
            .minus(Period.ofDays((random.nextInt(2685))));


    LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(random.nextInt(0, 23), random.nextInt(0, 59), random.nextInt(0, 59));

    return formatDate(LocalDateTime.of(date, time));
}

public static String formatDate(LocalDateTime date) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    return date.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(dtf);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Instant then = now.minus(2685, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    long millisBetween = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(then, now);
    Instant randomTime = then.plusMillis(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(millisBetween));
    
    System.out.println(randomTime);
```

Example output:

> 2019-09-13T10:21:21.078242Z

If you don’t want the fraction of second:

```
    System.out.println(randomTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
```

> 2019-09-13T10:21:21Z

I find it simpler to draw just one random number and let it decide the date and time rather than drawing the day and the time separately. `ThreadLocalRandom` has the advantage over `Random` of offering the option to draw a random `long` with a bound. Also tis way has the theoretical possibility of producing a time today, but only in the part of the day that has already passed.

I am exploiting the fact that the format you asked for agrees with what `Instant` produces from its `toString` method. The format is known as ISO 8601 and is an international standard (ISO is for International Organization for Standardization).

### Links

- [International Organization for Standardization](https://www.iso.org/)
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: very nice, me like it